# delete the first n rows of each ids in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a DataFrame, with two columns. I want to delete the first 3 rows values of each ids. If the `id` has **less or equal** to three rows, delete those rows also. Like in the following, the `id`s 3 and 1 have 3 and 2 rows, sod they should be deleted. for `id`s 4 and 2, only the rows 4, 5 are preserved.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df ['id'] = [4,4,4,4, 4,2, 2,2,2,2,3,3,3, 1, 1]
df ['value'] = [2,1,1,2, 3, 4, 6,-1,-2,2,-3,5,7, -2, 5]
```

Here is the DataFrame which I want.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number each "id" using `groupby` + `cumcount` and filter the rows where the the number is more than 2:

```
out = df[df.groupby('id').cumcount() > 2]
```

Output:

```
   id  value
3   4      2
4   4      3
8   2     -2
9   2      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Seriesmap.html) in order to performance a boolean indexing

```
new_df = df[df['id'].map(df['id'].value_counts().gt(2))]

   id  value
3   4      2
4   4      3
8   2     -2
9   2      2
```

Comment: I can not get your example output with above code ~ kindly check ~

Answer (score 0):

Using `cumcount` is the way but with `drop` work as well

```
out = df.groupby('id',sort=False).apply(lambda x : x.drop(x.index[:3])).reset_index(drop=True)
Out[12]: 
   id  value
0   4      2
1   4      3
2   2     -2
3   2      2
```